# Slider Revolution no sound with youtube video

Tags: wordpress

I used a nice youtube video in Revolution Slider on my Wordpress Site.
Today I updated Revolution Slider, because it wouldn't autoplay the video anymore in Google Chrome.
With the update (5.4.8) the video works again, but there is no sound.
The mute-feature is toggled to 'off'. Flipping is has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

> **IMPORTANT NOTE:** New Browser/Device restrictions for Autoplay Video
>   Videos with sound are no longer allowed to autoplay in Chrome, Safari and mobile devices. Because of this, Slider Revolution will automatically mute videos in these cases.

Source : [video-not-showing-up-on-mobile](https://www.themepunch.com/faq/video-not-showing-up-on-mobile/)

**Solution :**

Here is how you can enable sound on mobile devices..

We are using javascript to enable sound

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var v = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
    // check for the element to exist in dom
    var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
        if (v.length) {
            // run this code as soon as the element added to the dom
            var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)");
            if (isMobile.matches) {
               if(typeof v[0] != undefined){
                   v[0].autoplay = false; // you can change this as needed [true/false]
                   v[0].defaultMuted = false; // disable defaulMute 
                   v[0].muted = false; // disable mute(enable sound)
                   v[0].play(); // play the video
               }
            }
            clearInterval(checkExist);
        }
    }, 100);
});
</script>
```